# Color Issues When Moving from Pine Script v4 to v5

Tags: pine-script

## Original Script:

```
    version=4
//Basic Hull Ma Pack tinkered by InSilico 
study("Hull Suite by InSilico", overlay=true)
//INPUT
src = input(close, title="Source")
modeSwitch = input("Hma", title="Hull Variation", options=["Hma", "Thma", "Ehma"])
length = input(55, title="Length(180-200 for floating S/R , 55 for swing entry)")
lengthMult = input(1.0, title="Length multiplier (Used to view higher timeframes with straight band)")
useHtf = input(false, title="Show Hull MA from X timeframe? (good for scalping)")
htf = input("240", title="Higher timeframe", type=input.resolution)
switchColor = input(true, "Color Hull according to trend?")
candleCol = input(false,title="Color candles based on Hull's Trend?")
visualSwitch  = input(true, title="Show as a Band?")
thicknesSwitch = input(1, title="Line Thickness")
transpSwitch = input(40, title="Band Transparency",step=5)
//FUNCTIONS
//HMA
HMA(_src, _length) =>  wma(2 * wma(_src, _length / 2) - wma(_src, _length), round(sqrt(_length)))
//EHMA    
EHMA(_src, _length) =>  ema(2 * ema(_src, _length / 2) - ema(_src, _length), round(sqrt(_length)))
//THMA    
THMA(_src, _length) =>  wma(wma(_src,_length / 3) * 3 - wma(_src, _length / 2) - wma(_src, _length), _length)
//SWITCH
Mode(modeSwitch, src, len) =>
      modeSwitch == "Hma"  ? HMA(src, len) :
      modeSwitch == "Ehma" ? EHMA(src, len) : 
      modeSwitch == "Thma" ? THMA(src, len/2) : na
//OUT
_hull = Mode(modeSwitch, src, int(length * lengthMult))
HULL = useHtf ? security(syminfo.ticker, htf, _hull) : _hull
MHULL = HULL[0]
SHULL = HULL[2]
//COLOR
hullColor = switchColor ? (HULL > HULL[2] ? #00ff00 : #ff0000) : #ff9800
//PLOT
///< Frame
Fi1 = plot(MHULL, title="MHULL", color=hullColor, linewidth=thicknesSwitch, transp=50)
Fi2 = plot(visualSwitch ? SHULL : na, title="SHULL", color=hullColor, linewidth=thicknesSwitch, transp=50)
alertcondition(crossover(MHULL, SHULL), title="Hull trending up.", message="Hull trending up.")
alertcondition(crossover(SHULL, MHULL), title="Hull trending down.", message="Hull trending down.")
///< Ending Filler
fill(Fi1, Fi2, title="Band Filler", color=hullColor, transp=transpSwitch)
///BARCOLOR
barcolor(color = candleCol ? (switchColor ? hullColor : na) : na)
```

## AFTER Converting to v5:

```
    version=5
//Basic Hull Ma Pack tinkered by InSilico 
indicator('Hull Suite by InSilico', overlay=true)
//INPUT
src = input(close, title='Source')
modeSwitch = input.string('Hma', title='Hull Variation', options=['Hma', 'Thma', 'Ehma'])
length = input(60, title='Length(180-200 for floating S/R , 55 for swing entry)')
lengthMult = input(3.0, title='Length multiplier (Used to view higher timeframes with straight band)')
useHtf = input(false, title='Show Hull MA from X timeframe? (good for scalping)')
htf = input.timeframe('240', title='Higher timeframe')
switchColor = input(true, 'Color Hull according to trend?')
candleCol = input(false, title='Color candles based on Hull\'s Trend?')
visualSwitch = input(true, title='Show as a Band?')
thicknesSwitch = input(8, title='Line Thickness')
transpSwitch = input.int(40, title='Band Transparency', step=5)
//FUNCTIONS
//HMA
HMA(_src, _length) =>
    ta.wma(2 * ta.wma(_src, _length / 2) - ta.wma(_src, _length), math.round(math.sqrt(_length)))
//EHMA    
EHMA(_src, _length) =>
    ta.ema(2 * ta.ema(_src, _length / 2) - ta.ema(_src, _length), math.round(math.sqrt(_length)))
//THMA    
THMA(_src, _length) =>
    ta.wma(ta.wma(_src, _length / 3) * 3 - ta.wma(_src, _length / 2) - ta.wma(_src, _length), _length)
//SWITCH
Mode(modeSwitch, src, len) =>
    modeSwitch == 'Hma' ? HMA(src, len) : modeSwitch == 'Ehma' ? EHMA(src, len) : modeSwitch == 'Thma' ? THMA(src, len / 2) : na
//OUT
_hull = Mode(modeSwitch, src, int(length * lengthMult))
HULL = useHtf ? request.security(syminfo.ticker, htf, _hull) : _hull
MHULL = HULL[0]
SHULL = HULL[2]
//COLOR
hullColor = switchColor ? HULL > HULL[2] ? #00ff00 : #ff0000 : #ff9800
//PLOT
///< Frame
Fi1 = plot(MHULL, title='MHULL', color=color.new(hullColor, 50), linewidth=thicknesSwitch)
Fi2 = plot(visualSwitch ? SHULL : na, title='SHULL', color=color.new(hullColor, 50), linewidth=thicknesSwitch)
alertcondition(ta.crossover(MHULL, SHULL), title='Hull trending up.', message='Hull trending up.')
alertcondition(ta.crossover(SHULL, MHULL), title='Hull trending down.', message='Hull trending down.')
///< Ending Filler
fill(Fi1, Fi2, title='Band Filler', color=color.new(hullColor, 5))
///BARCOLOR
barcolor(color=candleCol ? switchColor ? hullColor : na : na)
```

After I upgrade the script, the colors get greyed out. I need them to show as they are in version 4. Appreciate all help. I tried changing the color function but have failed. I hope I am able to get the solution here.  Thank you very much
[Version 4 colors are visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dzOe.png)

[Version 5 colors are greyed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0kY0.png)

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using conditions to generate your colors. In this case, you cannot modify the colors via the Style tab. What you can do is to give the user some color options via the inputs.

See [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Colors.html#color-selection-through-script-settings) for more.

> As long as you don’t use colors whose RGBA components have to be
> calculated at runtime, script users will be able to modify the colors
> you use by going to your script’s “Settings/Style” tab.

## Edit:

Add the user inputs as shown below:

```
bull_color = input.color(#00ff00, "Bull Color")
bear_color = input.color(#ff0000, "Bear Color")
mid_color = input.color(#ff0000, "Mid Color")
```

Then modify the line where you set the color as below:

```
hullColor = switchColor ? HULL > HULL[2] ? bull_color : bear_color : mid_color
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  I understood the point but I am still unable to code it....

Comment: Can someone help me code this please?

Comment: See my edit please.

Comment: Thanks V, but it still is greyed out

Comment: It will be grayed out. You cannot fix that because your color depends on a condition. With the workaround I provided, you can change the colors via the user inputs.

Comment: I tried it. It doesn't show the colours.  Only the line thickness can be changed.

Comment: Youn eed to look at the the "Inputs" tab and not the "Style" tab.